# Remove values from a list given a condition on the first element

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

If I have a list like this:

`list = {{1, 2}, {4, 6}, {80, 90}, {800, 20}};`

How can a remove the values that are greater than let's say 13 or a given number based on the first element only? How would it be the same based on the second element?. I tried `DeleteCases[list, _?(# < 13 &)]` but this only works when the list is Flatten I think.

Thank you.

Comment: `DeleteCases[list, {_?(# < 13 &), __}]`? or `Select[list, #[[1]] >= 13 &]`?

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you! This works!